# How can I get the app's files directory in the companion object (static member) of MainActivity in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I'm developing an android app using Jetpack Compose. I need to get the app's files directory in the companion object (static member) of MainActivity. Basically, I need to initialise a static object with getFilesDir before ui content is created since that object will provide data for ui. I can't use 'LocalContext.current' and can't call 'this.applicationContext' from inside the companion object.

I added a latinit var and lazy initialisation in companion object. In the following Kotlin code calling "this.applicationContext" throws nullPointerException.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{myApp.frontend/myApp.frontend.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

This happens because applicationContext is not initialised before onCreate() method. Please help on how I can fetch filesDir to initialise member in companion object.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    init {
        dataDirPath = this.applicationContext.filesDir.absolutePath
    }

    private companion object {

        private lateinit var dataDirPath : String

        val myObj : MyObj by lazy { 
            newObject(dataDirPath)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need companion object? Also _private_ companion object means you can't access it outside of Activity, so simple `private val ...` will works same way. You can initialize in `onCreate` before `setContent` call.

Comment: I need companion object because I need a static member (not tied to an instance of class) which is created and initialised only once. onCreate is called multiple times while an app is running. And that member is not required outside activity.

Comment: OK, but what's the point of having a static property that is not accessible from outside the class? Or is the goal only to have it initialized strictly once?

Comment: MyObj has a member (eg. myObj.uiDataProvider() ) which is accessed inside `onCreate` and passed on to different screens. Initialising MyObj starts a resource intensive process, like starting a backend server.

Comment: See the answer below, it shows one way to avoid multiple initialization without using extra entities and objects. But [clean architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture#recommended-app-arch) implies that the things you're talking about have no place in Activity. I think Viewmodel is the best place to hold `MyObj`.

Comment: See [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle). Viewmodel scoped to the activity remains in memory until it finishes and this is exactly what it exists for - to [persist](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#viewmodel-benefits) data throughout the entire lifecycle of activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `context` post `onCreate` and you could get rid of `private companion` and move variable to global file level with private modifier, verify and initialise if it is not already initialised in `onCreate` that way it won't be initialised on every `onCreate`

```
private lateinit var myObj: MyObj

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    if(!::myObj.isInitialized){
      myObj = newObject(this.applicationContext.filesDir.absolutePath)  
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
 }
  
}
```